# How to get .aar sign (or HashKey) in runtime in android

Tags: android, sign, aar

Is it possible to get `aar` sign(or `HashKey`) in `runtime`?

i use below code for `apk` files and it works, but not for `aar` files

```
  PackageInfo info;
        try {
            info = Payment.this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(contex.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            Toast.makeText(Payment.this, contex.getPackageName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md;
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                Log.e("hash key", something);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

`getPackageName()` method get `apk` `packagename` because of this i will get `apk` sign not `aar`

Comment: What is your problem? Any log or error?

Comment: post edited (read last line), thanks

Comment: Nothing has changed!

Comment: this line added 
getPackageName() method get apk packagename because of this i will get apk sign not aar

Answer (score 0):

Get you context and pass it to the getSign method

```
public static String getSign(Context context, String algorithm) throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {

        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        int flags = PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES;
        PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
        try {
            packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, flags);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        Signature[] signatures = packageInfo.signatures;
        byte[] cert = signatures[0].toByteArray();
        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cert);
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = null;
        try {
            certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        X509Certificate certificate = null;

        try {
            certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(input);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        String hexString = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
            byte[] publicKey = messageDigest.digest(certificate.getEncoded());
            hexString = byte2HexFormatted(publicKey);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
            throw e1;
        } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return hexString;
    }

    private static String byte2HexFormatted(byte[] arr) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(arr.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            String hexString = Integer.toHexString(arr[i]);
            int l = hexString.length();
            if (l == 1) hexString = "0" + hexString;
            if (l > 2) hexString = hexString.substring(l - 2, l);
            stringBuilder.append(hexString.toUpperCase());

        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Sample:

```
   Context context = MyLibApp.getContext();

            String sha1Sign = null;
            try {
                sha1Sign = AppSigner.getSign(context, "SHA1");
            } catch (CertificateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
   Assert.assertNotNull(sha1Sign);
```

Comment: thanks, sha1Sign will return sign of aar file or sign of an apk that included aar file?

Comment: @Milad Did you find a workaround? I am facing the same problem

Comment: This part of code is not working as excepted, the returned signature is of the application and not of .aar

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we can't get the HashKey SHA1 or SHA 256 of signed .aar library ** in runtime because the signature is overrided by the application signature**. (Test with code of @Ehsan Mashhadi which return as the only application signature all the time)

If you plan to make an Anti-Tamper protection for your .aar library on **runtime mode**, it's not possible.

The only possible solution is to sign the aar on **compile** mode by **jarsigner**:

Sign the library with:

```
jarsigner -keystore mykeystore.keystore -storepass mypassword -signedjar lib-signed.aar -verbose lib.aar myalias
```

Verify the library with:

```
jarsigner -keystore mykeystore-public.keystore -storepass mypassword -verify -verbose -certs lib-signed.aar myalias
```

or by the gradle plugin of jarsign :

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
        def aarPath = "${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/lib-unsigned-release.aar"

        task.doLast {
            ant.signjar(
                    alias: android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias,
                    jar: aarPath,
                    keystore: android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile,
                    storepass: android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword,
                    keypass: android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword,
                    preservelastmodified: 'true')

            ant.verifyjar(
                    alias: android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias,
                    jar: aarPath,
                    keystore: android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile,
                    storepass: android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword,
                    keypass: android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)
        }
    }
}
```